# Kubernetes: Issue with 2 Ingress object with regex path

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I have 2 ingress objects

first-ingress.yml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: first-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt"
    acme.cert-manager.io/http01-edit-in-place: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - www.example.com
      secretName: example-tls
  rules:
    - host: www.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: first-service
                port:
                  number: 80
```

second-ingress.yml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: second-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt"
    acme.cert-manager.io/http01-edit-in-place: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - www.example.com
      secretName: example-tls
spec:
  rules:
    - host: www.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /test(/|$)(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: second-service
                port:
                  number: 80
```

The expectation is:

[www.example.com/test/whatever](http://www.example.com/test/whatever) -> second-service

[www.example.com](http://www.example.com) -> first-service

What I saw is that both [www.example.com/test/whatever](http://www.example.com/test/whatever) and [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) reach to the first-service

If I change the second-ingress to replace the regex with a static path, it will work. [www.example.com/test/whatever](http://www.example.com/test/whatever) will hit the second-service

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: second-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt"
    acme.cert-manager.io/http01-edit-in-place: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - www.example.com
      secretName: example-tls
spec:
  rules:
    - host: www.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /test
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: second-service
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Any idea why regex does not work? I need the rewrite-target rule, which is the reason I use the regex

Answer (score 0):

The regex that you posted is exactly the same as from the example from the [NGINX Ingress Controller docs](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/#rewrite-target), but the yaml file is wrong (one mistake with the double `spec`, below more information) - I tested your yamls files on Kubernetes v.1.21, NGINX Controller version v.1.0.2 and Cert Manager v1.6.1.

A few notes/thoughts about what may be wrong:

---

Instead of using twice `spec:` (`second-ingress.yaml`) , [use `spec` only once](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#tls). I did not observe the change in the behaviour in the prefixes itself, but in the `kubectl get ing` command for the second ingress there was no 443 port specified. When I ran `kubectl get ing second-ingress -o yaml`, there was missing TLS part.

**Before (wrong setup)**:
`second-ingress.yaml` file:

```yaml
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - www.example.com
      secretName: example-tls
spec:
  rules:
```

`kubectl get ing` output (missing port 443 for the second ingress):

```yaml
user@cloudshell:~/ingress-two-services $ kubectl get ing
NAME             CLASS    HOSTS             ADDRESS       PORTS     AGE
first-ingress    <none>   www.example.com   xx.xx.xx.xx   80, 443   5h7m
second-ingress   <none>   www.example.com   xx.xx.xx.xx   80        50m
```

`kubectl get ing second-ingress -o yaml` output (missing `tls` part):

```yaml
user@cloudshell:~/ingress-two-services $ kubectl get ing second-ingress -o yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
...
spec:
  rules:
  - host: www.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: second-service
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /test(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
status:
...
```

**After (good setup)**:
`second-ingress.yaml` file:

```yaml
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - www.example.com
      secretName: example-tls
  rules:
```

`kubectl get ing` output:

```
user@cloudshell:~/ingress-two-services $ kubectl get ing
NAME             CLASS    HOSTS             ADDRESS       PORTS     AGE
first-ingress    <none>   www.example.com   xx.xx.xx.xx  80, 443   5h18m
second-ingress   <none>   www.example.com   xx.xx.xx.xx  80, 443   61m
```

`kubectl get ing second-ingress -o yaml` output:

```yaml
user@cloudshell:~/ingress-two-services $ kubectl get ing second-ingress -o yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
...
spec:
  rules:
  - host: www.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: second-service
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /test(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - www.example.com
    secretName: example-tls
status:
...
```

---

Another thing worth noting that the modified configuration for the second ingress is behaving differently than the one that does not work for you.

Using `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2` + `path: /test(/|$)(.*)`:

- `www.example.com/test/` will rewrite the request to the pod to `/`
- `www.example.com/test/whatever` will rewrite the request to the pod to `/whatever`

However, using only `path: /test`:

- `www.example.com/test/` will rewrite the request to the pod to `/test`
- `www.example.com/test/whatever` will rewrite the request to the pod to `/test/whatever`

Please make sure that you are using a proper setup for which your app is designed to.

---

Other tips:

- make sure that ingress is applied by running `kubectl get ing` command
- get the logs of the NGINX Ingress Controller. Get the name of the Ingress Controller pod (`kubectl get pods -n ingress-nginx`) and then run `kubectl logs -n ingress-nginx ingress-nginx-controller-{...}`. Check how your requests are handled and where (which service) they are forwarded to
- check the logs of the pods from the deployments and check how they are handling request (`kubectl logs {pod-name}`)
- if you are using some out-dated version of the Kubernetes better upgrade it